# EXTJS 4.0 : how to implement callback method for store.sync() method?

Tags: callback, extjs4, store, synchronization

I am using Extjs 4.0 , and I need a callback method for `store.sync()` method? Does anyone have a solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still didn't find anything to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

This should work starting from 4.1:

```
store.sync({
            success: function()
            {
                console.log("success!!");
            },
            failure: function()
            {
                console.log("failed...");
            },
            callback: function()
            {
                console.log("calling callback");
            },
            scope: this
        });
```

Comment: +1 for this. While the original user requested ExtJS 4.0, I would consider upgrading within minor releases such as 4.1 to be the "correct" answer in my opinion. Lots of minor bugs were fixed between 4.0 and 4.1 and above, without many (perhaps any?) breaking changes.

Comment: Note that if there is nothing to sync, the callback isn't called at all... if you would like it to, you might have to use an override anyway...

Answer (score 1):

you can catch the result of each method in your store with

```
Ext.define('AM.store.AdreessStore', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
....

   onCreateRecords:function (records, operation, success) {
   },

    onUpdateRecords:function (records, operation, success) {
    },

    onDestroyRecords:function (records, operation, success) {
    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short question, short answer:

Try listening to the different events of store, like `datachange`, `update` or `load`. Maybe one of them (or a combination of them) fires when you need them.

Comment: no,It don't work well. The developer in extjs said they will fix this on 4.1 version. there is a solution about listening to the store proxy "exception" event for the failure case and listening to the "write" event on store for the success case. but not worked quite well for all the failure case,for example,I returned "success:false,msg:'failed!'" but no exception,then no response for the exception listener.